# Add URL rewrite rule on root website for specific URL

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Is it possible to apply a URL rewrite based on a matching URL after my website name? So say I have a rule on http://foo:8080 that enables me to go to http://foo:8080/ and that would rewrite to http://too. Is there a way to say that if I access http://foo:8080/bar it will take me to http://too/bar but have the rule on the website foo without any applications underneath it?

This would enable multiple rules on one site to reroute based on where I navigate to in the first place rather than setting up multiple applications for each rewrite rule.

I hope this makes sense, if it doesn't but you think you have an answer please let me know and I'll try to be more clear.

Thanks

Comment: Where/how are "foo" and "too" hosted?  Can you clarify "without any applications underneath it"? Are you able to bind both hostnames to the same IIS site, and use rewrites to serve the appropriate content?

Comment: "Foo" is hosted on a different server to "too". The rewrite at this point is a reverse proxy rewrite so going to "Foo" will rewrite to  "too" and then anything after the domain is appended to the new url. By no application underneath the root what I mean is no virtual folder in the iis. Just the top level website. Setting up a rule on the root website creates the rule for "anything after '/'" meaning directly after the website name there will be a rewrite. Creating an app and then adding the rule there adds the rewrite to anything after "/app/". I want to mimic that without the app.

Comment: Are you able to include the rewrite section of your web.config in your question? If you have the rewrite working for the bare domain, you can use a capture group in the input, then insert that value into the resulting rewritten URL? (then use conditions if you need to limit that behaviour to specific URLs instead of all urls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MisterSmith for pointing me in the right direction I found the answer to be the below, this also allows for http or https. My config now looks like the below:

```
 <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^bar/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://too:8080/bar/{R:1}" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

The rule is set on the website "foo" and now when I go to http://foo/bar/blahblahblah  I get a response from http://too:8080/bar/blahblahblah

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use rules with conditions such as the below.  The docs for URL Rewrite lists the variables available for your condition(s):  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference

```
...
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Foo Bar Too testing" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://too/{C:1}" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="/app/(.*)" />
            </conditions>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
...
```

The above rule (on foo) will only apply to paths starting with /app/, and the rewritten URL's path will not include `/app` prefix. You could modify this action to use `{C:0}` (the complete path) which would include the `/app` prefix in the rewritten URL.

Comment: I think your solution may work too but for my purposes it was not the correct answer. Thank you for all your help though, it led me in the right direction!

The solution was on the match url part of the config as per the answer i've added.